# Type of non-type parameter in template template class is non deducible in C++14 but deducible in C++17

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, c++17, template-templates

The title is a bit confusing but what I mean is this specific case:

```
template<class>
struct get_type_of_nontype;

template<class T, T Value, template<T> class Template>
struct get_type_of_nontype<Template<Value>> {
    using type = T;
};
```

So I can use it like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<int I>
class int_non_type {};

static_assert(
    std::is_same<typename get_type_of_nontype<int_non_type<0>>::type, int>::value,
    "T is deduced to be `int` as `template<T> class Template` is `template<int> class int_non_type`"
);
```

This works fine in C++17. In C++14 I get the following errors:

gcc 8:

```
<source>:5:8: error: template parameters not deducible in partial specialization:
struct get_type_of_nontype<Template<Value>> {
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:5:8: note:         'T'
```

clang 7:

```
<source>:5:8: error: class template partial specialization contains a template parameter that cannot be deduced; this partial specialization will never be used [-Wunusable-partial-specialization]
struct get_type_of_nontype<Template<Value>> {
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:4:16: note: non-deducible template parameter 'T'
template<class T, T Value, template<T> class Template>
               ^
```

And then they both complain that `struct get_type_of_nontype<int_non_type<0>>` is incomplete, so `typename get_type_of_non_type<int_non_type<0>>::type` can't compile.

Why is this different between C++14 and C++17? Is this just a compiler bug? If not, is there a way to do this in C++14?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Standard wording in [temp.deduct.type] paragraphs 13 and 14 changed.  So yes, your example is invalid in C++14, but is allowed in C++17 thanks to a new language feature.

C++14:

> A template type argument cannot be deduced from the type of a non-type *template-argument*.
>
> [*Example:*
>
> ```
> template<class T, T i> void f(double a[10][i]);
> int v[10][20];
> f(v);           // error: argument for template-parameter T cannot be deduced
> ```
>
> -- *end example*]

C++17:

> When the value of the argument corresponding to a non-type template parameter `P` that is declared with a dependent type is deduced from an expression, the template parameters in the type of `P` are deduced from the type of the value. [*Example:*
>
> ```
> template<long n> struct A { };
>
> template<typename T> struct C;
> template<typename T, T n> struct C<A<n>> {
>   using Q = T;
> };
>
> using R = long;
> using R = C<A<2>>::Q;    // OK; T was deduced to long from the
>                          // template argument value in the type A<2>
> ```
>
> -- *end example*] The type of `N` in the type `T[N]` is `std::size_t`. [*Example:*
>
> ```
> template<typename T> struct S;
> template<typename T, T n> struct S<int[n]> {
>   using Q = T;
> };
>
> using V = decltype(sizeof 0);
> using V = S<int[42]>::Q;  // OK; T was deduced to std::size_t from the type int[42]
> ```
>
> -- *end example*]
>
> [*Example:*
>
> ```
> template<class T, T i> void f(int (&a)[i]);
> int v[10];
> void g() {
>   f(v);         // OK: T is std::size_t
> }
> ```
>
> -- *end example*]

This seems a bit related to another C++17 template change: C++17 is the first version to allow placeholder types in non-type template parameters, as in `template <auto Value>` or `template <auto* Ptr>`.  I'd expect compiler implementations would need some similar logic for supporting both of the two language features.

Comment: Oh so `T` is deduced from `T Value` and not `template <T> class`. This makes it sound like there is no way to do this at all in C++14.

Comment: Probably not. Unless maybe you only need to support a finite list of types like the arithmetic types, in which case you could write a specialization for each one.