# Type conflicts in non-type template argument deduction

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, template-argument-deduction, non-type-template-parameter

```
#include<type_traits>

template <typename T, T>
struct A { };

template <typename T, T t>
void f(A<T, t>) {
}

int main() {
    f(A<const int, 0>{});
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/n6bcj5rjM

---

The program is accepted by GCC and ICC in C++14 and C++17 mode, as well as Clang in C++14 mode but rejected by Clang in C++17 mode and MSVC in either mode.

---

Rejections are with diagnostics like this:

```
<source>:12:5: error: no matching function for call to 'f'
    f(A<const int, 0>{});
    ^
<source>:7:6: note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'T' ('const int' vs. 'int')
void f(A<T, t>) {
     ^
```

---

Also consider the following variation:

```
const int i = 0;

int main() {
    f(A<const int&, i>{});
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/oa3xfv4jx

The same compilers still accept/reject and those rejecting now complain about a type mismatch between `const int&` and `int`.

---

Which compiler(s) are correct?

---

I expect the answer to depend on whether it is before or after C++17, since C++17 introduced a (breaking) change in non-type template argument deduction, see [[diff.cpp14.temp]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/diff.cpp14.temp).

In particular for C++17 and later I am wondering whether deduction of `T` from the argument for `t` is supposed to deduce the type of the template parameter, which would be `int` in the first variant (because top-level `const` is ignored) and `const int&` in the second variant, or whether the usual expression adjustments are supposed to be applied as in deduction with `auto ... = t;`, in which case the second variant should deduce `T` to `int`.

Is it then really intended that template argument deduction fails if these types mismatch with the explicitly provided type for `T`?

Comment: 2 observations - (1) the type of  `0` is `int` not `const int` and (2) if you make the change `f(A<int, 0>{});` then the code is accepted by all compilers.

Comment: _I would like to understand what the rules here are for the deduction of `T`_ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55033649/type-of-non-type-parameter-in-template-template-class-is-non-deducible-in-c14?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Regarding the duplicate: I am not concerned with whether or not the type can be deduced from the non-type argument, but whether 1. the non-type template argument should be used to deduce `T` at all, since `T` is already specified by the first template argument and 2. whether the deduction should yield `int`, the type of the value `0`, or `const int`, the type of the non-type template parameter of the specialization. In the former case deduction should fail, I guess, but in the latter it shouldn't.

Comment: _the non-type template argument should be used to deduce `T` at all, since `T` is already specified by the first template argument_ https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.deduct.type#9.sentence-1 (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.deduct.type#8.sentence-2)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I have removed the `static_assert` part, since that was indeed stupid. Your other links seem clear, but that still leaves the question of whether or not  deducing `T` to `int` from the non-type template argument should really cause deduction failure, so that Clang is the only correct one in both modes. That at least seems unintended to me.

Comment: @user17732522 _I have removed the static_assert part, since that was indeed stupid_ But the type of NTTP is `const int` and `decltype` shall produce it.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.param#6 seems to say that `const` is ignored.

Comment: Another interesting variation `template <typename T, std::remove_reference_t<T> t> void f(A<T, t>) {}` is accepted by all while `template <typename T, std::remove_reference_t<T>& t> void f(A<T, t>) {}` is accepted by gcc and msvc in both modes and rejected by clang and icc in both modes.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I assume you are referring to the first code example. `std::remove_reference_t<T>` results in `T` not being deduced. That is also how it should be before C++17 in the original. In that case, I think there should indeed not be a conflict (the types are correct before deduction). I am not sure what the intention with `std::remove_reference_t<T>&` is, but that seems to effectively result in what [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71283266/auto-deduction-of-reference-template-argument-from-not-reference-type-in-c?noredirect=1&lq=1) asks about.

Comment: @user17732522 Yes, I was thinking about the first example. My second variant was to try to force the non-type parameter into a `T&` but msvc won't accept `template <typename T, T& t> void f(A<T, t>) {}` (`const` vs. non-`const` ambiguity). Removing the ref first makes msvc also accept it. I actually came to this question via the question you referred to :-)

Answer (score 1):

The explanation given below is for the 1st snippet(also shown below):

```
//----------------------v--->i named the parameter for explanation purposes
template <typename T, T p>
struct A { };

template <typename T, T t>
void f(A<T, t>) {
}

int main() {
    f(A<const int, 0>{});
}
```

##### Step 1

Here we consider what happens for the *expression* `A<const int, 0>{}`.

From [temp.param#5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.param#5):

> The top-level cv-qualifiers on the template-parameter are ignored **when determining its type.**

On the first glance it seems that when applied to the given snippet, the non-type template parameter named `p` should be `int` instead of `const int`.

But note the emphasis on the highlighted part in the above quoted statement. In particular, my interpretation of this(the phrase "when determining") is that the top-level cv-qualifiers are dropped **when deducing the template parameter and so not when the template arguments are explicitly specified**.

And since in my given snippet, we are explicitly specifying the template argument, there is no template argument deduction(TAD) here. Thus, the dropping of the top-level cv-qualifiers due to the above quoted [temp.param#5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.param#5) does not happen. Meaning the **type of `p` is `const int`** instead of `int`.

Note that i may be wrong in interpreting [temp.param#5] above.

---

But before further analysis, from [temp.param#6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.param#6):

> **A non-type non-reference template-parameter is a prvalue**. It shall not be assigned to or in any other way have its value changed.

Moreover, from [expr#6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr#6):

> If a prvalue initially has the type “cv T”, where T is a cv-unqualified non-class, non-array type, the type of the expression is **adjusted to T prior to any further analysis**.

When applying [temp.param#6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.param#6) and [expr#6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr#6) to the given snippet, it means that `p`(a prvalue) will finally be of type `int` instead of `const int`.

Thus, the non-type template parameter **`p` is of type `int`**.

##### Step 2

Next, we consider what happens for the *call expression* `f(A<const int, 0>{})`.

Now currently we have a prvalue `A<const int, 0>` whose first type parameter `T` is `const int` while the second non-type template parameter `p` is of type `int`. Thus, for the function template `f<>` the first template type parameter `T` is deduced to be `const int` while the type of non-type template parameter `t` is deduced to be `int`. Thus there is a conflict between the type of `T` and hence the mentioned error saying:

```
<source>:7:6: note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'T' ('const int' vs. 'int')
void f(A<T, t>) {
     ^
```