# Auto-deduction of reference template argument from not-reference type in C++

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, template-argument-deduction

In the following program there are

- struct `A<int>` template, and
- function template `f<I>` having `const int&` template argument, and `A<I>` function argument:

```
template<int>
struct A {};

template<const int & I>
void f(A<I>) {}
 
int main() {
    const static int a = 0;
    f<a>(A<a>{}); // ok in GCC and Clang
    f(A<a>{});    // ok in GCC
}
```

The function can be called explicitly specifying template argument `<a>` in GCC and Clang.

But auto-deduction of template argument works only in GCC, while Clang complains:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'f'
note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'const int' against 'int'
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/G86dxh9jo

Which compiler is right here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71087779/type-conflicts-in-non-type-template-argument-deduction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Clang is right.

According to [temp.deduct.call]/4

> In general, the deduction process attempts to find template argument values that will make the deduced `A` identical to `A` (after the type `A` is transformed as described above). However, there are three cases that allow
> a difference: [...]

`A` is the transformed argument type used in the call. The transformations referred to include certain conversions (e.g. array to pointer decay) that are not relevant here. Importantly, *only the **type** `A` can be considered* for the deduction (not the form of the actual argument), and the type `A` is `A<0>`. From the type `A<0>`, how can GCC deduce what the template parameter `I` (of type `const int&`) should be?

It can't be a reference to `a`, because the fact that the 0 came from `a` is not part of the type of the argument `A<a>{}`. I think GCC is materializing a temporary and taking `I` as a reference to that temporary. But [temp.arg.nontype]/3.1 bans this, so the result ought to be a deduction failure.

Comment: Thanks, I reported GCC bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=107124