# Template parameter type deduction fails in GCC, not in Clang

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, language-lawyer

Consider the following code ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/K8zKTczoE)):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits> // std::false_type, std::true_type


template <typename t_tuple, auto t_size = std::tuple_size_v<t_tuple>>
struct test : std::false_type {};

template <typename t_tuple>
struct test<t_tuple, 0> : std::true_type {};


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    static_assert(test<std::tuple<>>::value);
    return 0;
}
```

Clang and some other compilers accept the code but in GCC and ICC the static assertion fails. Either changing the type of `t_size` from `auto` to `std::size_t` or casting the zero in the specialisation to `std::size_t` alleviates the issue. What I would like to know is:

1. Should I be able to pass the zero in the specialisation as `int` instead of `std::size_t` when setting the type of the second template parameter to `auto`? Obviously (?) the types do not match (since the type of `std::tuple_size_v` is `std::size_t`) but I was expecting the compiler to at least warn me about something.
2. Is there a best practice for using `auto` with non-type template parameters?

(I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71087779/856976) but it had to do with `const`/`volatile`.)

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/c9PM9q4a1

Comment: *"but I was expecting the compiler to at least warn me about something."* For what?, you might specialize also for any `test<T, Value>`, (template doesn't have to be called with default (i.e `test<std::tuple<>, 42>`).

Comment: Adding extra specialization (for `std::size_t(0)`) makes instantiation ambiguous for clang/msvc [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hea7qs6s4)

Comment: Off topic: simplified version just works: https://godbolt.org/z/PY3Wbnh9h

Comment: That is intresting. Dropping `auto` in favor of `std::size_t` fixes the issue: https://godbolt.org/z/EnbfK5EYh on all compilers.

Comment: @Jarod42 I thought that varying the type of a non-type template parameter would not be possible and hence the compiler would warn me (but citation needed).

Comment: Based on this example: https://godbolt.org/z/KbMGTeodE I would say gcc is right here.

Comment: @tsnorri not sure what you mean by *"varying the type of a non-type template parameter would not be possible"*, you can definitely specify **any** parameter as `t_size`.

Comment: With full specialization of `auto`, all compilers agree on behavior [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1W9rjevzs). With partial, they disagree [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/W4br3q5Mv)

Comment: If I recall correctly, using `auto` as the type of a non-type template parameter effectively introduces a hidden unnamed type parameter, that has to be deduced from the non-type template argument. Roughly, you have `template <typename t_tuple, typename Auto, Auto t_size = std::tuple_size_v<t_tuple>> struct test;` Then, `struct test<t_tuple, 0>` specializes `test<t_tuple, int, 0>`, but `test<std::tuple<>>` invokes `test<std::tuple<>, size_t, 0>`

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. In @Jarod42’s [example](https://godbolt.org/z/W4br3q5Mv), it looks to me that GCC is correct when partial specialisation is used, is this the case?

Comment: *"Restore"* deleted comment: related [CWD issue #1647](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/1647) [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/so6xaqKGs).

Comment: @Jarod42 change `auto t_size = std::tuple_size_v<t_tuple>` to `std::size_t t_size = std::tuple_size_v<t_tuple>`, and the OP problem won't reproduce. So this is not because `0` is of `int` type which is not `size_t`